# Yii2 Unregistered Jquery.js

Tags: yii, yii2

How I can Unregistered jquery.js in Yii2,Like register method is:

```
    $this->registerJs();

    $this->registerJsFile('/web/js/my.js', ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution! just open your config file `config/web.php`

under component paste this code.

```
   'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            // you can override AssetBundle configs here       
             'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'js' => [] 
            ],        
        ],
    ],
```

Now view source,jquery.js file removed.

Comment: Wouldn't the correct way be to remove the assetBundle using jquery from the view? And if you're trying to change the version of jquery then possibly doing it in the composer.json would be correct.

Comment: Also i cant see a way to remove assets in a per view fashion.. yii fails again....

Answer (score 0):

remove yii\web\YiiAsset from your AppAsset.php